# Knees (cartilage?) hurt when squatting

Tags: squats, flexibility, knees, knee-pain

Both my knees (and even more so, my left knee) hurt when I squat down and stay in that position for 3-4 minutes. There's a dull pain that gets worse the longer I stay squatting, and when I stand up, the pain flares up and stays that way for a few minutes. Is this a flexibility issue, and how do I resolve it? I've been facing a lot of flexibility issues with my shoulders and knees lately.

Comment: This is really something that you need to ask a physio about. We can't tell if it's just inflexibility, something is being pinched or if something is structurally wrong.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, that makes sense. Thank you for your input.